# Global utf8_encode

Tags: php

Is there a way to apply utf8_encode globally? I'm trying to get the entire page to load different languages properly without having to insert utf8_encode before every variable.

```
 echo '<p>'.utf8_encode($LANG_CALL_TO_ACTION).'</p>'
```

Comment: just have all your languages in utf-8

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have to use `utf8_encode` this frequently is probably a symptom of an architectural problem.

`utf8_encode` is a function that converts iso-8859-1 encoded data to UTF-8.

In a modern setup, you won't need to use it at all: The incoming data will already be UTF-8 encoded.

If it is not, if the data comes from a legacy ISO-8859-1 database (which is totally okay), you should use an appropriate output encoding instead of UTF-8 (i.e. in this case ISO-8859-1).

It is also possible to globally convert the data if really, really necessary, but to give any advice on that, we'd need to know *much* more about your setup. It also is probably a bad idea to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have to.  `utf8_encode()` is for converting an ISO-8859-1 string into a UTF8 encoded one - it does you no good if your data is already UTF-8 and you're just having display issues.

What it seems to me like you're after is to make sure all of your contents is displayed correctly as UTF-8, for which you just need to set the proper HTTP header.

My preferred method for doing so is this

```
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
```

Comment: yup, this could be the solution too. It will depend on the OP's clarification what the issue really is

Comment: Tried your code and header ("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8;"); We're still having trouble displaying Turkish

Comment: If you have turkish content, then `utf_encode()` is definitely not going to help you - you can't express turkish in ISO-8859-1.  It sounds more like you're have encoding issues at the database level, or wherever this data is coming from.

Comment: @Pekka What information do I add to my question? Double byte Turkish characters aren't appearing.

Comment: @cubers pretty much everything: What kind of site you are running, where your data comes from, how it is encoded, what code you are using to fetch the data, what output encoding you have declared on your site....